# Should I use either Linear Mixed Models or ANOVA to analyse my data or can I use a mix of both?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, lme4-nlme

**Background**

Following the guidance in Andy Field's Discovering Statistics Using R textbook I understand that before using Linear Mixed Model (LMM) analysis it is first necessary to assess the need for a multi-level model (p. 878). To do this you compare a (1) baseline model that includes only the intercept to (2) a model that allows random intercepts. If allowing intercepts to vary significantly improves the model fit (tested using the anova() function), then it makes sense to pursue the multi-level approach. Alternatively, if there is little evidence of variation across subjects then using a mixed ANOVA is better alternative.

(1) Baseline model

```
interceptOnly <- gls(dependent_variable ~ 1, data = data, method = 'ML', na.action = na.exclude)
```

(2) Random intercept model

```
randomIntercept <- lme(dependent_variable ~ 1, data = data, random = ~1|subject, method = 'ML', na.action = na.exclude)
```

Compare these models

```
anova(interceptOnly, randomIntercept)
```

**Question**

I wish to run several analyses and report them in the same paper (e.g., tests on different outcome measures). If, for some of these outcome measures it makes sense to use a LMM (i.e., random intercepts provides a better model fit) but for others it makes sense to use a mixed ANOVA (i.e., random intercepts does not provide a better model fit), is it okay to use different analytical approaches throughout the paper, or would it be better to pick one approach (LMM or mixed ANOVA) and stick with it for consistency?

Thank you in advance.